# sudo apk: command not found on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, amazon-web-services, sudo

I'm attempting to install SQL Server driver on AWS SageMaker Notebook instance running Amazon Linux 2. I am following the documentation here - Alpine Linux section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

When I attempt to install after downloading using the following commands, I get an error:

```
#Install the package(s)
sudo apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql18_18.1.1.1-1_amd64.apk
sudo apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools18_18.1.1.1-1_amd64.apk

sudo apk: command not found on Linux
```

Linux version:

```
5.10.102-99.473.amzn2.x86_64
```

What do I need to do before running the commands?

Comment: I may be mistaken as I've never used Amazon Linux, but I believe the package manager is `yum` not `apk`.  So the installation instructions may be a bit closer to the redhat example than the Alpine example.

Comment: @JNevill i get `permission denied` error when running: `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/8/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo`

Comment: Because you are running that curl output into `/etc/` you will need to use `sudo` in front of that.